localStorage stores opposite theme values in React component
I want to store the current theme in the localStorage. I'm using the useEffect hook which should store the current theme but for some reason, it is storing "light" for the dark theme and "dark" for the light theme.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ThemeSwitch = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");
  function changeTheme() {
    setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light");
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("Theme", theme);
  }, [theme]);
  return (
    <div className={theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light"} id="container">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <button
        className={theme === "light" ? "light" : "dark"}
        onClick={changeTheme}
      >
        Change Theme
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default ThemeSwitch;

I expected that upon clicking the button, the function changeTheme would be called, updating the theme state and triggering a rerender of the component. During the rerender, the value in the localStorage will be updated as per my knowledge. Why then it is storing opposite values ("light" for the dark theme and "dark" for the light theme)? Thank you for your explanation.

className={theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light"} <-- you're setting the class to "dark" for light theme and vice versa

And you could properly simplify this to className={theme}

when changeTheme is called, the theme state is not immediately updated. Instead of that, React schedules an update and continues executing the subsequent lines of code. so, when you try to set the item in localStorage immediately after calling setTheme, it hasn't yet updated the state.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const ThemeSwitch = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  function changeTheme() {
    const newTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    setTheme(newTheme);
    localStorage.setItem("Theme", newTheme);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    //here you must get the theme from localStorage on component mount
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("Theme");
    if (storedTheme) {
      setTheme(storedTheme);
    }
  }, []); // make sure to leave this Empty dependency array to run only once on mount

  return (
    // ... rest of your code
  );
};

export default ThemeSwitch;

